# Q: Trying to make a counting timer in lua

Tags: lua

I am completely new to Lua. I am trying to make a timer that counts up and then stops. I have written a function timer that does most of the job but it counts up without stopping. How do I make it stop at lets say 50 or 100?

```
startTime = os.time()
count = 1
while 1 do
        if os.difftime(os.time(), startTime) == 1 then
                print (count)
                count = count + 1
                startTime = os.time()
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use the condition of your while loop.

```
while count <= 50 do
-- your code
end
```

or a repeat loop

```
repeat
  -- your code
until count == 50
```

or you use the `break` keyword to prematurely leave any loop.

```
if count == 50 then
  break
end
```